# backup command on HP-UX fail

Tags: unix, backup, hp-ux

I have two biggest file and i am trying to take backup of them to a tape drive.
the operate system is HP-UX and the directory of the tape drive is `/dev/rmt/2m`.

The command that i perform for backup was `tar cvf /dev/rmt/2m file1` and after that the `file2`

But when i use the command to view the file

```
tar tvf /dev/rmt/2m
```

that command show me that i have only 1 file backup ( the last `file2`).

Please can you help on this.
where is the problem ? The problem is on backup command or the command to view the file.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for HP-UX but maybe device you use is autorewind so you should change the device or use `tar` on this way:

```
tar cvf /dev/rmt/2m file1 file2
```

Or you can try to use

```
tar cvf /dev/rmt/2mn file1
tar cvf /dev/rmt/2mn file2
```

as this driver is not autorewind

Comment: Hi, The both files are too big and should take one by one.

Comment: If both files can be stored in to the tape IMO the size is not important. Just try

Comment: I have tried but the command shoe me that the size is to big.

Comment: how big they are?

Comment: the files inside contains to much info inside and they are .gz in the end. i have tried to take both in one command but is imposibile.

Comment: ok but where the difference beetwen 2m and 2mn that you have used  and how to show if both files are backup ?

Comment: First is autorewind, second is not. You can rewind the tape and check with tar

Comment: What is wrong? This is the same tape, but driver behave differently depend of how to use it!!!

Comment: Right, use it and check the result

Comment: No offense, but have you read some documentation about HP-UX? `mt -f /dev/rmt/2mn rewind;tar tvf /dev/rmt/2mn`

Comment: i have used this but as i show you on the question this command doesn't show me all the files but only 1.

Comment: @endrimi, did you test my solution?